# Debug .net 1.1 code from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I am attempting to debug a .net 3.5 web application.  This application is using a business object that was created in .net 1.1.  I have a strong suspicion that my error of (stackoverflow) is coming from my .net 1.1 assembly.  I have access to the .net 1.1 code and can rebuild/recompile it.  However I was hoping there is a way for me to step into it from my .net 3.5 application.

Is there any way of getting this done?

Comment: That sounds hopeful (by which I mean: unlikely), to be honest...

Comment: Not "natively"  - you can only do this from 2.0 onwards. But maybe you could hack your way around it if static analysis of the old code doesn't reveal the issue. Create a simple webservice (asmx) to host the old code (in VS2005 or whatever it is), maybe introduce a simple function to invoke the business object in whatever way you feel will cause the crash, run it and set breakpoint. Then add reference to the webservice in your fancy new fangled 3.5 app, and call the invoker function via the auto-generated proxy.
The 1.1 webservice project will break for youthen and you can step through it.

Answer (score 0):

So figured out that if I recompile the .net 1.1 assembly in debug mode and copy both the assembly and the .pdb file to the .net 3.5 project that is using it I can than step into the 1.1 code.  What will happen is VS2010 will ask for the location of the .net 1.1 source code and than allow you to step into it.

Now you can't edit it or anything however you can step though it and see where the failure is.